# In Hebrews 4:16, what/where is the "throne of grace"?

Tags: hebrews, metaphor

> [Heb 4:16 NKJV] Let us therefore come boldly to the throne of grace, that we may obtain mercy and find grace to help in time of need.
>
> > [Heb 4:16 mGNT] προσερχώμεθα οὖν μετὰ παρρησίας τῷ θρόνῳ τῆς χάριτος ἵνα λάβωμεν ἔλεος καὶ χάριν εὕρωμεν εἰς εὔκαιρον βοήθειαν

Is this an actual chair that one approaches, a metaphor or an allusion to something? How might one "approach" said chair?

Comment: Those who have boldly approached it in experience, will be they who can comment upon it - I would suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What does the “throne of iniquity”<sup>1</sup> signify but the rule of one who is full of, and thus characterized by, iniquity? Likewise, “God sits upon the throne of His holiness,”<sup>2</sup> for “God is holy.”<sup>3</sup> He sits upon the throne of glory,<sup>4</sup> for He is “the Father of glory”<sup>5</sup> whose glory is supreme.<sup>6</sup> He sits upon the **throne of grace**, for He is “gracious,”<sup>7</sup> whose very Spirit is the “Spirit of grace.”<sup>8</sup>

Christians come to the throne of grace by believing in the Lord Jesus Christ, “for in [him] we have boldness and **access** (**προσαγωγὴν**) with confidence by the faith of him.”<sup>9</sup> By faith, the apostle Paul also wrote that Christians “have **access** into this grace wherein we stand,”<sup>10</sup> and “through [the Lord Jesus Christ], we both have **access** by one Spirit unto the Father.”<sup>11</sup>

On the Greek word προσαγωγή, LSJ notes,<sup>12</sup>

[image: LSJ, p. 1500, προσαγωγή, II., 2.]

By believing in the Lord Jesus Christ, Christians also covenant with God and receive His grace.

Philo wrote,<sup>13</sup>

> <sup>52</sup> And covenants are written for the advantage of those worthy of the gift, **so that a covenant is a symbol of grace**, which God has placed between Ηimself who proffers [it] and man who receives [it], <sup>53</sup> and this is the preeminence of well-doing, nothing being between God and the soul except virgin grace.
>
> <sup>ΝΒʹ</sup> διαθῆκαι δὲ ἐπʼ ὠφελείᾳ γράφονται τῶν δωρεᾶς ἀξίων, **ὥστε σύμβολον εἶναι διαθήκην χάριτος**, ἣν μέσην ἔθηκεν ὁ θεὸς ἑαυτοῦ τε ὀρέγοντος καὶ ἀνθρώπου λαμβάνοντος <sup>ΝΓʹ</sup> ὑπερβολὴ δὲ εὐεργεσίας τοῦτό ἐστι, μὴ εἶναι θεοῦ καὶ ψυχῆς μέσον, ὅτι μὴ τὴν παρθένον χάριτα.

---

#### Footnotes

<sup>1</sup> Psa. 94:20
<sup>2</sup> Psa. 47:8
<sup>3</sup> Psa. 99:9
<sup>4</sup> Jer. 14:21
<sup>5</sup> Eph. 1:17
<sup>6</sup> Psa. 148:13
<sup>7</sup> Psa. 116:5
<sup>8</sup> Heb. 10:29 cf. Zec. 12:10
<sup>9</sup> Eph. 3:12
<sup>10</sup> Rom. 5:2
<sup>11</sup> Eph. 2:18
<sup>12</sup> LSJ, p. 1500, προσαγωγή, II., 2.
<sup>13</sup> “On the Changes of Names,” §52–53, p. [166](https://archive.org/details/philonisalexandr0103philuoft/page/166/mode/1up)

#### References

Philo of Alexandria. [*Philonis Alexandrini Opera Quae Supersunt.*](https://archive.org/details/philonisalexandr0103philuoft/) Ed. Cohn, Leopold; Wendland, Paulus. Vol. 3. Berlin: Reimeri, 1896–1898.

Comment: So the "throne" is a metonym for "the kingdom of God". Nice answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

The Phrase "throne of grace" is unique in the NT at Heb 4:16.  This phrase should not be separated from the subsequent reason - "to find mercy".  The picture here is of the sinner approaching the Jesus as High Priest and judge to obtain mercy and grace.

Such a judgement seat was a common idea in the Greco-Roman world and appears often in the NT using the word βῆμα (béma) which occurs in about a dozen places and is used literally of earthly settings such as Matt 27:19, John 19:13, Acts 12:21, 18:12, 16, 17, 25:10, 17.  It is also used of the heavenly court in Rom 14:10, 2 Cor 5:10.

It is in this latter setting that probably alludes to the כַּפֹּ֫רֶת (kapporeth) of the OT, that is the "mercy seat" which covered the Ark of the Covenant that was a symbol of the celestial throne of God.  Some versions translate this as "atonement cover" or similar, Ex 25:17-22, 26:34, 20:6, 31:7, 40:20, Lev 16:2, 13-15, Num 7:89, 1 Chron 28:11.  It was here that Moses interceded with God, etc.

This throne of God appears in the NT frequently, Matt 5:34, 23:22, Heb 4:16, 12:2, 7:15, 20:12.  In this final reference God's throne is depicted as the throne of Judgement where the righteous find mercy and grace but the wicked are condemned.

CONCLUSION

The "throne of grace" is where repentant sinners find mercy in God's judgement.  It is welcomed by the righteous and dreaded by the wicked - see the "thrones" of God in Matt 25:31, 32; Rev 6:15-17; Rev 20:4-6; Rev 20:11-15.

Comment: Thank you for making the connection with the kapporeth. So how much of this is allusion and how much is real or metaphor? How does one "approach"?

Comment: I do not know the answer to the latter to questions.  I assume that the answer is "prayer".  We are told almost nothing about the physical layout of heaven (assuming that is even meaningful) so I will assume it is a human term to explain a heavenly process that is otherwise incomprehensible.

Comment: What about Hebrews 9:11ff? Does that figure into this?

Comment: That would be background but significantly "is not part of this creation" and so is beyond description.  The throne depicted as in the heavenly tabernacle (Rev 11:19, 15:1-4), etc.

Answer (score 3):

[Heb 4:16 NKJV] Let us therefore come boldly to the throne of grace, that we may obtain mercy and find grace to help in time of need.

> [Heb 4:16 mGNT] προσερχώμεθα οὖν μετὰ **παρρησίας** τῷ θρόνῳ τῆς
>   χάριτος ἵνα λάβωμεν ἔλεος καὶ χάριν εὕρωμεν εἰς εὔκαιρον βοήθειαν

Basic Lexicon of Ancient Greek (Online)

ΛΗΜΜΑ

**παρρησία** ,  ουσιαστικό   -ας   , ἡ

ΣΗΜΑΣΙΟΛΟΓΙΚΟ

Α. η ελεύθερη έκφραση γνώμης, το να εκφράζει κανείς την άποψή του με θάρρος και ειλικρίνεια, η παρρησία |η δοτ. ως επίρρημα παρρησίᾳ=με θάρρος έκφρασης, απροκάλυπτα, ανοιχτά Β. αθυροστομία, απρόσεκτη και αναιδής έκφραση γνώμης

Google Translation.

IMPORTANT

A. free expression of opinion, expressing one's opinion with courage and sincerity, parsimony. as an adverb parisisiᾳ = with courage of expression, openly, openly B. athyrostomy, careless and arrogant expression of opinion.

Approaching God’s throne through prayer.  God by means of his grace,  grants us the blessing of approaching his heavenly throne in prayer. In fact, Paul calls God's  throne “the throne of grace " and invites us to approach it “with freedom of expression-in  prayer ." God has afforded us this privilege through his Son, “by means of whom we have this freeness of speech and free access with confidence through our faith in him.”

ΠΡΟΣ ΕΦΕΣΙΟΥΣ 3:12 1881 Westcott-Hort New Testament (WHNU)

> 12 εν ω εχομεν την **παρρησιαν** και προσαγωγην εν πεποιθησει δια της
>   πιστεως αυτου

Free access to God in prayer is indeed a wonderful expression of his grace.